# using php function to allow users to select their dob from drop down list

Tags: php, html

I saw from online somewhere a method to let user select their DOB using a Drop down list using php function. This is a selection of it:

```
<select name="monthOfBirth">
<option value="">---Select month---</option>
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

I tried it and it works, but can anybody explain to me what this does:

```
<option value="<?php echo ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
```

I know it will list down the date but I do not understand the `..?'0'.$i ; $i;..` part. Can anybody explain to me?

Comment: So you have a pathological hatred of people born before 1980? But are quite content with people less than a year old entering their date of birth. Ageist!

Comment: @MarkBaker ohyes i should probably change the year to 1901 I guess. I'm sorry i'm quite new to this as I was just introduced to php a few weeks ago.

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: The particular line of code you're asking about makes sure that date values are 2-digits, so `1` becomes `01`, `2` becomes `02`, etc

Comment: @Mark: What if his targetaudience is 16 to 25yr olds? This would be perfectly fine ;) Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a short if/else:

```
// This
echo ($i <10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
// Is the same as this:
if( $i <10){ echo '0'.$i;}
else{        echo $i;}
```

**It adds a zero if less than 10**.

You could do this too:

```
if( $i <10){ echo '0';}
echo $i;
```

*Edit: You wrote `$1` instead of `$i` in your code, and got a `>` where a `<` was needed*

Comment: Noted the mistake. Thanks for the help. :)